# How to properly sort/arrange Class Members

Tags: python, c++, coding-style

I am sure this question was already answered couple of times, and i will soon close this topic, but i couldn't find it.

**Is there a recommendet way of arranging member functions?**

I am pretty sure not everything need rules, but wanted to if there are thoughts about this topic, which goes more then sorting by access level.

Example class in Pseudocode:

```
Class
     amethod()
     bmethod()
     cvariable
     avariable
     bvariable
```

Comment: In C++, the order of the member declarations matter insofar as it determines the order that they are initialized when you instantiate an object of that class. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12222509/2297365).

Comment: @huu True of C++, but what I know about Python you can put inside the head of a pin. Conflating the two is probably a bad idea, but I'm willing to wait for Olaf to swing by and confirm that hypothesis.

Comment: @user4581301, didn't mean to conflate the two. The SO answer I linked is specifically for C++. I'll clarify this in my comment.

Comment: Sorting members lexicographically can give a quick visual index, which sometimes is good, but it could be difficult to enforce.  Another implication in C/C++ is the layout of the class in memory though.  This can affect space needed for padding alignments (size in memory), as well as cache locality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some recommendations, but they are rather vague. The only common point is, quoting the [Google Java Style Guide, § 3.4.2,](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s3.4.2-class-member-ordering)

> that each class order its members in ***some* logical order**, which its 
>   maintainer could explain if asked. For example, new methods are not just 
>   habitually added to the end of the class, as that would yield "chronological 
>   by date added" ordering, which is not a logical ordering.

The [Google C++ Style Guide](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.html#Declaration_Order) recommends to order by visibility (which is obvious for C++), then by type:

> - Typedefs and Enums
> - Constants (static const data members)
> - Constructors
> - Destructor
> - Methods, including static methods
> - Data Members (except static const data members)

Oracle’s [Code Conventions for Java, § 3.1.3,](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-141855.html#1852) recommend to order by type, then by visibility (for variables) or functionality (for methods):

> - Class (static) variables (ordered by visibility)
> - Instance variables (ordered by visibility)
> - Constructors
> - Methods (grouped by functionality rather than by scope or accessibility)

Comment: (Why 66% of your answer are about Java?)

Comment: @deviantfan Because I am more familiar with the Java conventions and because the thoughts behind the recommendations (esp. ‘have a logical order’ and ‘group by functionality’) also apply to most other languages. I’m happy if someone can add recommendations from PEPs or other Python resources.

Comment: After some research: I could not find any recommendations for Python in the standard resources (PEP 0008, Google Python Style Guide, ‘Hitchhiker’s Guide to Python’, popular projects).

Answer (score 2):

I´m not aware of any generally/widely accepted convention, other than "use something that makes sense" (eg. grouping variables instead of writing a wild mix of vars and functions).

However, it´s not only a style question:

In C++ (and C), the order maps directly to the memory layout, this can [lead to different variable sizes because of alignment and padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306186/structure-padding-and-structure-packing). Additionally, if serializing something in a binary format, where which value is in the data is of course important (but serializing that way is not exactly good, *because* the memory layout depends...).

And, like @huu noted in the comments, the variable order determines the initialization order, this is important a member variables is initialized with the value of another member variable (of the same object). A mismatch in variable declaration order and initialization order will lead to a compiler error.

Comment: A slight correction here, a mismatch in the variable *declaration* order and the initializer list order will cause a compiler warning, unless `-Wall` is specified, which of course makes all warnings errors.

Comment: @huu `-Wall` doesn't make all warnings errors, `-Werror` does. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Comment: @cmorse, ah yes, you're correct. `-Wall` enables warning messages