# How to set char* to NULL using default constructor in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor

I am trying to set this char* to NULL using a default constructor.
But I am facing trouble.
The problem is with the line where I am using a default constructor and setting `m_name=NULL;`

```
class Car {
    char *m_name;
    int m_carnum;
public:
    Car() :m_carnum(0), m_name = NULL {} //this line has the error
    ~Car(){}
};
```

While this code seems to be working:

```
Car() :m_carnum(0) {
    m_name = NULL;
}
```

So I why isn't this working ?

m_name = NULL;

Comment: If you have a problem, **EXPLAIN YOUR PROBLEM**. And read [ask]

Comment: You say `m_name = NULL;` is working. You then ask why `m_name = NULL;` isn't working. That doesn't make sense. You don't have `m_name = NULL;` in your non-working version, you just have `m_name = NULL`. Not that it would work if you inserted a semicolon there, but it's important to be precise. The compiler is, and if you're not, you're sure to get a lot of other problems in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you are dealing with a pointer, the following might be advisable (considered good practise) if using C++ 11 and beyond:

```
Car() : m_name(nullptr), m_carnum(0) {}
```

The reasoning behind this is outlined here (among other places with a quick search):
[What are the advantages of using nullptr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816385/what-are-the-advantages-of-using-nullptr)

Comment: Good practice would be not using `char *` to store a name

Comment: @berilac Thank you for a great answer.

Comment: @M.M fair point. Might you recommend `std::string`? Is it still reasonable to consider `char*` for variable length names; or would it be better to allocate `char []` of a set size if you know the names will never be larger?

Comment: `std::string` is certainly the simplest option

Answer (score 1):

Instantiate it like your int. You also need to make sure you instantiate member variables in the order they are declared (see [Why should I initialize member variables in the order they're declared in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222417/why-should-i-initialize-member-variables-in-the-order-theyre-declared-in))

```
Car() : m_name(0), m_carnum(0) 
{}
```

Comment: Nice answer. But some explanation on this advice `make sure you instantiate member variables in the order they are declared` would be nice.