# How to interpret this CPP constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor

Here the 'StackFrame' is a constrcutor, with two arguments viz., _caller and _kf.

```
StackFrame::StackFrame(KInstIterator _caller, KFunction *_kf)
: caller(_caller), kf(_kf), callPathNode(0), 
 minDistToUncoveredOnReturn(0), varargs(0) {
locals = new Cell[kf->numRegisters];
}
```

I am unable to understand what does the  ' : caller(_caller), kf(_kf), callPathNode(0),    minDistToUncoveredOnReturn(0), varargs(0)' stand for?

Comment: This should be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/2079303

Comment: And this [What's the differences between member initializer list and default member initializer on non-static data member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36600187/whats-the-differences-between-member-initializer-list-and-default-member-initia)

Comment: This is the member initializer list. See, for example, here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor

Answer (score 1):

It is called member initalizer list. It initializes the specified member to specified values.

For example `caller(_caller)` sets the member caller to the value of _caller, `callPathNode(0)` sets the value of `callPathNode` to `0`.

[More information here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor)